# Malicious code found in popular Wordpress Plugin?

Tags: php, security, wordpress, eval

Its part of a widely used plugin, I tried to decode it but couldnt. Its too scrambled. It doesnt look too good it has so far I found out it has these:

Function Calls gzinflate 5 base64_decode 5 strrev 10 str_rot13 5 define 1

Here is the code:

```
http://pastebin.com/QfBBJhZH
```

I would like to know to report the plugin on the wordpress community and to the authority websites.

P.S I do not mention the plugins name in case this is a false accusation and this thread reaches high in SERPS and damages their reputation.

Comment: contact the plugin supplier. it may be just 'legitimate' obsfication to stop modification.

Comment: I have already 9days ago but no reply, thats why I am worried. Also the new update he issued caused a fatal error and now I cant see the plugin in the wordpress plugins list, but I see it in ftp plugins directory. If this is malicious code, over 30k people have been infected. I will continue to try to decode it and post back.

Comment: If the plugin is in the Repository, contact `plugins@wordpress.org`. Obfuscated code is [not allowed](http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/guidelines/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decode results:

```
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PASS_KEY_1', '`Ip%z/U7GVxv;efuSJRh<@JDipw(j#b9vqa)Eu9djt{nC|n+X=&^+QVz0NiisyF' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PASS_KEY_2', '3"t=5h\MCOdx_l;*]qB\TksgI{winpe),b-[_"OpO]]&...(R*N*TY3Ys@Lc4Lh' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PASS_KEY_3', '4*){(oK575;ns4d*1?lo0N{nD}x-X:v3"vVz7>b;QB6X(9%[&5eW3[G^JY]B)J%' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PASS_KEY_4', ':-#x0U&B37}a\8\6K)YQ1/#ss3>CzBJEGB3"SvqPTCb2Fv"F!3EV-Ur=I#w0sym' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PASS_KEY_5', 'SR-5]e_]^~k(BQC.a{V16EeAV*~03wAJ6|c99oEv\OWf;3GqH:5_FuLnY8!z53x' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PASS_KEY_6', 's#9]%>Xja`.]G2Ab@Dt-BKgfB1,Z~bI0na!c7zMkH\@ds64\n+zwp\F/z5rr[@z' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_LICENSE_UNLIMITED', 'IJUlRXqWfOOGxpZOXPtu1JWgMxC92kgGszuA1dYyCKCV4AkqeTAcp4vuAkmRqa9' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_LICENSE_DEVELOPER', 'NMMRUG1p3kpPZLfC6rNNuQxiDp5WM8Sw8iI9Um2ZcYooGgbtFjMYovJaqTxVk8M' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_ADMIN_NONCE', 'Gkk0EByKA5isMfC56M3QzvnskpJeH0MVYABj1MdHUwNOGmA1Bpq6SuHngQYs90r' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_ADMIN_NONCE_FIELD', '_rpnonce' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_ADMIN_OPTIONS_NAME', 'pxsg_wpri_admin_options' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_ADMIN_FORM_ACTIVATION', 'activation' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_ADMIN_FORM_DASHBOARD', 'dashboard' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_ADMIN_FORM_SETTINGS', 'settings' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_ADMIN_FORM_LICENSE', 'license' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_ENABLED_YES', 'yes' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_ENABLED_NO', 'no' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_POST_META_PING', '_pxsg_wpri_ping' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_POST_META_PINGS', '_pxsg_wpri_pings' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_POST_META_LAST_PING', '_pxsg_wpri_last_ping' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_HASH', 'tiger192,4' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PING_PENDING', 'Pending' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PING_PROCESSING', 'Processing' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PING_COMPLETED', 'Completed' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_CRON', 'pxsg_wpri_cron' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_TRIGGER', 'pxsg_wpri_trigger' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_TRIGGER_PING', '1' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_TRIGGER_PING_SITE', '2' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_POST_ID', 'post_id' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_LOG_DIRECTORY', 'logs' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_INC_DIRECTORY', 'inc' );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_TIME_LIMIT', 0 );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_TRIGGER_PING_TIMEOUT', 3 );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PING_TIMEOUT', 10 );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PING_PENDING_TIMEOUT', 300 );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_PING_PROCESSING_TIMEOUT', 600 );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_DEFAULT_LOG', 30 );
define( 'PXSG_WPRI_DEFAULT_INTERVAL', 1000000 );
```

Comment: +1 thumbs up for Asaf thank you the code doesnt seem to be malicious. Could you please explain briefly how you managed to do it? I have been trying to decode it for over 5 hours.

Comment: Just replace the eval with echo function until you get it. (In this case I did it somthing like 10 times)

Comment: Thanks for replying, so basically to decode any eval sort of thing I just echo and whatever it gives just replace eval to echo and again until its final no more evals? Did I understand correct?

Comment: One more question Asaf, how did u pass this part: eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(strrev($qSRGBiUitdcnQkKpAryU))));

Comment: Just print the eval() part, you will get the result with another eval, print it too until its final no more evals.
After you print an eval you shloud delete the eval code and paste the result instead.